# Angular ui-sref, param removes spaces? Workaround for it?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ui-sref

I have an anchor tag:

```
<a ui-sref="view({id:{{ id }}})" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="View Details"><i class="fa fa-search-plus fa-2x icon-color"></i></a>
```

The id value I am getting here is "ID - 100"(including the spaces). When I click on this link, the URL it gets moved to is "view/-100". Notice that it has removed the text characters before the "-" and the spaces as well.

This results in the incorrect data being passed. 
Not exactly sure how to pass this value? (Hoping to find the solution in a ui-sref. Not using ng-click ).

Thanks in advance.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6mpbfk3c/

Note that in console you will see this error:

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/-100"

Comment: Shouldn't you only be passing `100` anyway and not `ID - 100`?

Comment: Confusing ... in you're example you are using `posts.details.about({postId: USL - 100})`  - if this is a String wrap it with `''`... ?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The id that I am passing is a part of result set. So it is basically in this format..    posts.details.about({postId: {{post.id}}})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look, it must be helpful.
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/but0fcb4/)

```
<button ui-sref="posts.details.about({postId: 'USL - 100'})">Load Post Details About</button><br/>
```

Comment: You are a genius.. :)
Was banging my head for so long for this simple issue.. :D 
Thanks a lot for all your comments.
I did this: `posts.details.about({postId: '{{post.id}}'})`